# ISO decoding issue perl

Tags: regex, perl, encoding

I have the string which contains

```
$string = "&amp;&reg;";
```

when I do `HTML::Entities::decode($string);`  it's returning me the `&&reg;` from that I figured out that this function is unable to decode ISO codes http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

then I tried some other things like, but yet no success

```
Encode::decode('utf8', '&reg;') // returns &reg;
Encode::decode_utf8('&reg;') // returns &reg;
```

then I tried to manually replace it using regex  pattern,

```
$string =~ s/&reg;/®/g;
```

but the above line converted it into **&Â®**, can some one please tell me how to decode these ISO characters, and in case of manual replace why **Â** is coming ?

Comment: The authoritative doc for entities is [in the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#named-character-references), not in the unreliable w3schools. Anyway, I cannot reproduce: `perl -CS -MHTML::Entities -E'say decode_entities "&amp;&reg;"'` produces expected output, using an up to date H:E v3.69 on perl v5.18.1. What versions are you using?

Comment: perl 5.14.2 normal output too (HTML::Entities 3.69 too)

Comment: Re: "it's returning me the `&&reg;`", that's not true, it returns `&®`.

Comment: Re: "but the above line converted it into `&Â®`", You did not provide enough information. Please answer the following three questions: What's your script's encoding? Did you use `use utf8;`? What encoding does your terminal expect?

Comment: @ikegami Yes I am trying to decode some html encoded text, to the UTF8 so that I can see &reg; to ®

Comment: huh? None of my question can be answered with "yes", and what follows doesn't pertain to my questions.

Comment: Please do not take w3schools as an example. See http://www.w3fools.com/.

Answer (score -1):

Try to `use utf8;`. this works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Encode;

my $s = '&reg;';

$s =~ s/&reg;/®/g;

print encode('utf8', $s);
```

Comment: after utf-8 encoding it became like Ã‚Â®

Comment: please answer to ikegami's and amon's questions